# Quota Max Message Size exceded (default 65536)

Tags: c#, wcf

I am gettting each time I exceded the maximum quota size and that I have to use MaxReceivedMessageSize to increase it because as you know by default is 65536 bytes.

In my web.config I think it is right when I increase that property but I don't know why i am recieve yet that error message.

I was reading in similar errors here in stackoverflow and I was testing that examples but i didnt get the solution.

The wcf is workingif I don't exceded 65536 bytes.

My web.config is:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connection" value="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=david;Uid=root;Pwd=root;"/>
    <add key="uploads" value="C:\Users\DMR\Google Drive\DESARROLLO\PHP\android\contents\img\uploads\"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Android.Android">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="Android.IAndroid"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00" >
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

How can I increase the quota to the max?

What is wrong in my `web.config`

Comment: The rest of the code is working, When data, as I said is not longer than that quoto works fine

Comment: could you please clean and rebuild your application and try?

Comment: David, you have to change the config in both client and server

Comment: I cleaned, rebuild and restart the IIS wasnt the solution, anyway how can I change cliente? in the same way like the server (or service)?

Comment: Micky was true what you said, I could configure the client test WCF and it is working now I set the maximus size of an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

after to fight a little this morning i got to configure the WCF, I had change the client test WCF with this configuration and client side in web.config:

[image]

I get this solution in the next link, it is very clear: http://www.lemursolution.com/node/175

My final web config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="connection" value="Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=david;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" />
    <add key="uploads" value="C:\Users\DMR\Google Drive\DESARROLLO\PHP\android\contents\img\uploads\" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" closeTimeout="01:50:00" openTimeout="01:50:00" sendTimeout="01:50:00" receiveTimeout="01:50:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="128" maxStringContentLength="8388608" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
        </binding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAndroid" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" />

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://dmr-pc/Android/Android.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAndroid" contract="IAndroid"
          name="BasicHttpBinding_IAndroid" />
    </client>

    <services>      
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="Android.Android">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding" contract="Android.IAndroid" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>      
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name=" MyClient">
          <dataContractSerializer ignoreExtensionDataObject="false" maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```